# Facing errors while working on backend side of whatsapp clone in MERN STACK

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, npm, pusher-js

While working on backend of whatsapp clone i am facing these errors couldn't understand what type of errors are?
This Project is made using React, Node, Express and Mongodb. I also use pusher.
E:\Whatapp clone\whatsapp-backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:289
throw new error_1.MongoParseError(`${optionWord} ${Array.from(unsupportedOptions).join(', ')} ${isOrAre} not supported`);
^

```
MongoParseError: options usecreateindex, useunifedtopology are not supported
    at parseOptions (E:\Whatapp clone\whatsapp-backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:289:15)
    at new MongoClient (E:\Whatapp clone\whatsapp-backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:62:63)
    at E:\Whatapp clone\whatsapp-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:784:16

    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (E:\Whatapp clone\whatsapp-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:781:19)
    at E:\Whatapp clone\whatsapp-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:342:10
    at E:\Whatapp clone\whatsapp-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (E:\Whatapp clone\whatsapp-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (E:\Whatapp clone\whatsapp-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1176:10)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

On your mongoose.connect() you need to omit `useCreateIndex` and `useUnifiedTopology` as they are no longer supported.

[From the docs:](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#no-more-deprecation-warning-options)

> No More Deprecation Warning Options useNewUrlParser,
> useUnifiedTopology, useFindAndModify, and useCreateIndex are no longer
> supported options. Mongoose 6 always behaves as if useNewUrlParser,
> useUnifiedTopology, and useCreateIndex are true, and useFindAndModify
> is false. Please remove these options from your code.

Comment: I have  installed previous version of mongoose@5.13.2. Facing other issues now